# SCSS change variable out of scope from inside @if

Tags: sass

Is there any workaround for the situation, when you want to modify a variable outside of the scope of your function? :

```
$ui-theme: 'pink';

@if $ui-theme == "pink" {
    $ui-main: #eb82b0;  
    $ui-secondary: #fff5f9;
    $ui-third: #f6c2d9;
} @else {
    $ui-main: #ff8067;  
    $ui-secondary: #fff6e5;
    $ui-third: #ffb1a2;
}

a { color: $ui-main; background: $ui-secondary };
```

I want to create a global variable called `ui-theme` which will define `$ui-main, $ui-secondary...` in all other code written below the definition. It seems that the variable scope is also applied when using directives like `@if`.

Does anyone knows how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to initialize your variables outside of the control block:

```
$ui-theme: 'pink';

$ui-main: null;
$ui-secondary: null;
$ui-third: null;

@if $ui-theme == "pink" {
    $ui-main: #eb82b0;  
    $ui-secondary: #fff5f9;
    $ui-third: #f6c2d9;
} @else {
    $ui-main: #ff8067;  
    $ui-secondary: #fff6e5;
    $ui-third: #ffb1a2;
}

a { color: $ui-main; background: $ui-secondary };
```

Output:

```
a {
  color: #eb82b0;
  background: #fff5f9;
}
```

It might be nicer to just do theming via `@include` rather than hard coding variables like that.

_pink.scss:

```
$ui-main: #eb82b0;  
$ui-secondary: #fff5f9;
$ui-third: #f6c2d9;
```

styles.scss:

```
@include "pink"; // or don't include anything if you want the default colors

$ui-main: #ff8067 !default;
$ui-secondary: #fff6e5 !default;
$ui-third: #ffb1a2 !default;

a { color: $ui-main; background: $ui-secondary };
```