# SASS output multiple different files by variables

Tags: css, sass

I am working on a project that involves different themes for each subpage. Each subpage has the exact same HTML markup as a frame, but on every subpage, the same elements - such as headings - must have different colors.

The way I am tackling this problem is to have every single declaration that differs on subpages in their corresponding CSS files, such as red.css or blue.css. These files contain only the color declarations of the selectors that must be different, so font-sizes and everything else is in the global CSS file.

What I am hoping to accomplish is to have the color variables declared in a file and create a SCSS frame for the theme CSS files that include the corresponding variables for the CSS declarations. In a more clear way:

Example of the variable declarations:

```
$red: red;
$blue: blue;
```

And the theme frame SCSS file should look something like this:

```
h1 {
   color: $heading-color;
}
```

And the goal is to make SASS loop through the variables and create an X number of different CSS files that have the same frame, but each of them should have their corresponding values at the right places, so blue.css should have the blue values, red should have the red values, etc.

Is this possible to do? What I'm trying to avoid is to make X SCSS files with the exact frame in it, but with different values for their values, as this means X number of editing every time something changes.

Comment: That seems like a lot of work. Is there some reason why you can't just target the body of each page with a class and then adjust your CSS/SaSS/SCSS accordingly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Sass Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552529/dynamic-sass-variables)

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742238/scss-change-variable-out-of-scope-from-inside-if

Comment: @Paulie_D valid point, I could just do that, but... I am one of those freaks, who don't like to use non-semantic classes in my markup... Now, in this case, of course, technically, adding a simple class to my body would be the 100% best option, I was just curious whether or not this method was possible at all.

Comment: Classes aren't `semantic` as such anyway. If if that was a concern how is a class of `.homepage` non-semantic? It does exactly what it says on the tin.

Comment: I mean semantic as in [BEM](http://bem.info/). Basically, it's just a personal preference to rid the markup from classes such as `red` or `blue` - not even in such way as naming the themes by a naming convention of any sort. I would like to use modifying classes for only JavaScript state modifications.

Answer (score 0):

With SASS you can import files which contain common CSS rules. Just create 2 files, each with different variables definition and include everything other from another scss file. Like this:

theme1.scss:

```
$primaryColor: red;
$secondaryColor: blue;
@import 'all';
```

theme2.scss:

```
$primaryColor: orange;
$secondaryColor: violet;
@import 'all';
```

_all.scss

```
/*All your CSS rules including for example:*/
h1 {
    color: $primaryColor;
}
```

SASS will compile into 2 files theme1.css and theme2.css but there is no need to write duplicate CSS.