# Making GUI skins with SASS

Tags: css, sass, mixins, skin

I'm building an [HTML5 App](http://ghostlab.vanamco.com) that needs to have different skins applied by the user. I'd be keen to hear the best way to go about this with SASS. I'm new to SASS and this solution works but there must be a better way. The method applies and extra class that i'm sure is not needed.

My idea is to compile and ship two css files and then let the user choose over a select tag.

Any advice?

This is some example code that i'm using now:

The "mixin" _skin.scss

```
$skin: default-skin; // Default skin
//$skin: dark-skin; //  Dark skin

.default-skin { // Default Skin
    @import 'skins/_default-skin';
}

.dark-skin { // Dark Skin
    @import 'skins/dark-skin';
}

// Applying the Skins

html {
  @if $skin == default-skin {
    @extend .default-skin;
  } @else if $skin == dark-skin {
    @extend .dark-skin;
  } @else {
    @extend .default-skin;
  }
}
```

The default skin partial

```
.nav{
  background: $gray-light;
  button{
    color: $white;
    &:active{
      color: $gray-lighter;
    }
  }
}
```

And the dark skin partial

```
.nav{
  background: $gray-darker;
  button{
    color: $black;
    &:active{
      color: $gray-dark;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SCSS change variable out of scope from inside @if](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742238/scss-change-variable-out-of-scope-from-inside-if)