# Creating a mixin for color themes with SASS

Tags: css, variables, sass, themes, mixins

I would like to create various themes in my project (I work with SASS 3.2) :

I defined a variable:

```
$themeName: Z;
```

I tried to create a mixin like :

```
@mixin theme($themeName) {
  @if $themeName == Z {
    @content;
  }

  @if $themeName == Y {
    @content;
  }
}
```

To be able to use like that:

```
.wrapper {
  @include theme(Y) {
    border-top: 5px solid blue;
  }
  @include theme(Z) {
    border-top: 10px solid red;
  }
}
```

But in my CSS file, I have something like that :

```
.wrapper {
  border-top: 10px solid red;
  border-top: 5px solid blue;
 }
```

I'll appreciate a lot some help, I spend hours trying to find a solution to easily develop various themes for my platform.

Comment: There are better ways of going about this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742238/scss-change-variable-out-of-scope-from-inside-if or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882528/unexpected-results-when-using-extend-for-themes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling mixin two times, each time for a different theme. Mixin remaining unchanged, try this:

```
$currentTheme: Z;

.wrapper {
    @include theme($currentTheme) {
        border-top: 10px solid red;
     }
}
```

And alter $currentTheme at the beginning of .scss file to which theme you are currently using (Y, Z, A, B, X...), meaning: which theme do you want to see in generated .css file.

EDIT: Thanks for clearing everything up in the comment, now the solution:

```
$currentTheme: "Z";

@mixin isTheme($theme) {
    @if $theme == $currentTheme {
        @content;
    }
}

.wrapper {
    @include isTheme("Z") {
    border-top: 10px solid green;
}  
    @include isTheme("Y") {
        border-top: 10px solid blue;
    }
}
```

Just change $currentTheme variable as you see fit (in this case to "Y", just to see that it actually works).

Comment: You can see my code [here](http://sassmeister.com/gist/2039683de516fc21336e). My goal is to have differents css definitions for each theme. I would like to be able to generate different css files, changing only my theme's variable.

Comment: My god ! You are the best ! I didn't understand how I don't see that before ! Thanks, thanks a lot @bardzusny !