# How to assign to a global variable in Sass?

Tags: scope, sass, variable-assignment

I run this Sass code:

```
$a: 1;
@if 2 + 2 == 4 {
    $a: 2;
}
@debug $a;
```

I expect to see 2. The output, however, is:

```
Line 5 DEBUG: 1
```

I understand that Sass creates a new `$a` variable inside the `@if` scope. How can I change this behaviour and assign a value to the global `$a`?

I use Sass 3.4.0.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742238/scss-change-variable-out-of-scope-from-inside-if - but here the variable didn't exist before, here it is not the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you're using Sass 3.4+, you should append the `!global` flag to your variable declaration:

```
$a: 1;
@if 2 + 2 == 4 {
    $a: 2 !global;
}
@debug $a; // will output 2
```

The original [SASS_REFERENCE](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variables_) on variable declaration stated:

> "Variables are only available within the level of nested selectors
>   where they're defined. **If they're defined outside of any nested
>   selectors, they're available everywhere.**

but the [SASS_CHANGELOG of 3.4+](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html) shows that this behaviour has changed:

> All variable assignments not at the top level of the document *are now
>   local by default*. **If there’s a global variable with the same name, it
>   won’t be overwritten unless the `!global` flag is used.**
>
> For example, `$var: value !global` will assign to `$var` globally. This behavior can be detected using `feature-exists(global-variable-shadowing)`.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question being asked.

Comment: @cimmanon This is a *complement* of answer (maybe I should have add as a comment instead). This is the justification of `!global` use, the 'rational' way not the "trial-and-error"..

Comment: No one asked for justification or history or anything else.  This is not a forum.   Answers are for answering the question being asked, and you are not answering the question.

Comment: FWIW, it seems to me that this is very close to being an actual answer. In particular, it does include the documentation that explains that the use of `!global` is required. In that respect, this is a better answer than the accepted one. All that's left is for the author of this answer to actually provide the necessary syntax. Given that that syntax is already provided by the other answer, it seems redundant to expect it to be shown here. At most, this answer could quote or otherwise reference the other answer for that aspect.

Answer (score 8):

By trial-and-error, I found a solution: I have to add `!global` in the assignment.

```
$a: 1;
@if 2 + 2 == 4 {
    $a: 2 !global;
}
@debug $a;
```