# Dynamic output of sass maps?

Tags: css, sass

say this (sass maps):

```
$small:(
  side-spacing: 14px
);

$medium-aux:(
  side-spacing: 28px
);

$large:(
  side-spacing: 38px
);
```

Is there a way to build a 'function' that outputs the above, receiving the values? Like (fake):

```
build_spacings(14px, 28px, 38px);
```

---

They asked me why this is not a duplicate question: I'm speaking specifically of sass maps, and not necessarilly global ones.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign to a global variable in Sass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260790/how-to-assign-to-a-global-variable-in-sass)

Comment: While that question can hold a path to one possible solution to this one, it's not the same thing. People looking for sass maps thing, would find this and maybe not that. Here we're not explicitly speaking of globals.

Answer (score 1):

You can set those global variables if you use the `!global` keyword.

Here is working code that will generate the maps in your question:

```
@mixin build_spacings ($s, $m, $l) {
  $small: (
    side-spacing: $s
  ) !global;

  $medium-aux: (
    side-spacing: $m
  ) !global;

  $large: (
    side-spacing: $l
  ) !global;
}

@include build_spacings(14px, 28px, 38px);
```

You can see it working at [SassMeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/e8bcd7bda429baa4da9392b025554922).